# How to merge two element in a array Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, duplicates

I just get stuck here....

I have get a list from my database with can have same Id_Plane but different DateCreated, Starts, Ends...

How do I compute 2 element with same ID to 1 element with 2 DateCreated, Starts, Ends

Thanks

Here is my data for example

[image: Example data here]

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: ya but need to get all the element in each element to reuse...


Now I display two array in vue like this

[1] https://i.imgur.com/7Sv5WlG.png
Need to convert to display like this
[2]: https://i.imgur.com/SAFhiDA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will give you an array with unique 'Id_plane' by keeping the first object data.

```
let data = [
            {
                DateCreated: "2020-10-10",
                Ends: 15.5,
                Id_plane: 1,
                Id_sale: 4,
                Id_scheduler: 6,
                Starts: 7,
                __isset_bitfield: 31
            },
            {
                DateCreated: "2020-10-11",
                Ends: 17,
                Id_plane: 1,
                Id_sale: 4,
                Id_scheduler: 6,
                Starts: 7,
                __isset_bitfield: 31
            },
            {
                DateCreated: "2020-10-12",
                Ends: 17,
                Id_plane: 2,
                Id_sale: 4,
                Id_scheduler: 6,
                Starts: 4.2,
                __isset_bitfield: 40
            },
            {
                DateCreated: "2020-10-11",
                Ends: 17,
                Id_plane: 2,
                Id_sale: 4,
                Id_scheduler: 6,
                Starts: 7,
                __isset_bitfield: 31
            },
        ];
        data.map((item, index) => {
            let matchingItems = data.filter(el => el.Id_plane === item.Id_plane);
            matchingItems.map(matchingItem => {
                let key = data.indexOf(matchingItem)
                if (key !== index) {
                    data.splice(key, 1);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and response to you soon.! Have a nice day, sir!

Comment: Thanks. I tried it .... got the result have unique with Id_plane.... but seem like it dont merge 2 element while matching to 1.... because I need the datecreate, starts, ends of each element....

Comment: Can you please add an example result here. Thank you.

Comment: Oh but from your work that I have to filter the different Id_plane ... Now I had solved it. Thanks for your solution somuch

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to return a new list based on the id_plane.

```js
let list = [
 {
   id_plane: 1,
    date_created: "2020-10-10"
  },
  {
   id_plane: 1,
    date_created: "2020-10-11"
  },
  {
   id_plane: 4,
    date_created: "2020-10-12"
  },
  {
   id_plane: 10,
    date_created: "2020-10-13"
  },
  {
   id_plane: 1,
    date_created: "2020-10-14"
  },
  {
   id_plane: 4,
    date_created: "2020-10-15"
  }
];

var ids = list.map(e => e.id_plane).filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) == i);
var arr = {};

ids.forEach(i => {
 arr[i] = list.filter(e => {
   return e.id_plane === i;
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ya but need to get all the element in each element to reuse...


Now I display two array in vue like this

[1] https://i.imgur.com/7Sv5WlG.png
Need to convert to display like this
[2]: https://i.imgur.com/SAFhiDA.png

Comment: @Dũng each `arr` element key refers to Id_Plane column, and the values are the rows that have the Id_Plane as it's parent, just loop it